# Trigger code when there is incoming mail to update the incoming email

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to update all incoming emails.

The code triggers when an email comes in, however, it updates the mail item which was 'selected' at that point in time not the new mail.

The 'Run Script' option is not available and our IT is not ready to change the registry.

```vb
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
Call InsertNum
End Sub

Sub InsertNum()
Dim Mail As Outlook.MailItem

Set Mail = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)

Mail.Subject = "10" & Mail.Subject

Mail.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `NewMail` event, use [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171304%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - it passes a list of the entry ids that you can use to call `Namespace.GetItemfromId`.

Answer (score -1):

The [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/application-newmailex-event-outlook) event handler provides the EntryID string of the received item.

```
void MyApplication_NewMailEx(string anEntryID)
{
  Outlook.NameSpace namespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");  
  Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox );
  Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem) outlookNS.GetItemFromID( anEntryID, folder.StoreID );

  // ... process the mail item
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your quick response. However, it throws error... I am not clear how to fix it. I am very new to Outlook VBA, sorry.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What line of code throws an error?

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I have shown the errors in arrows.

Sub InsertNum()
Dim Mail As Outlook.MailItem
-->> the below 2 lines is showing "Method or Data Member not found"
Outlook.NameSpace NameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Outlook.MAPIFolder Folder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
-->> the below line is showing Syntax error
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem) outlookNS.GetItemFromID(anEntryID, folder.StoreID)